# Compare two nested lists in Python

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists:

```
list_a = [["the", "ball", "is", "red", "and", "the", "car", "is", "red"],
          ["the", "boy", "is", "tall", "and", "the", "man", "is", "tall"]]
list_b = [["the", 0], ["ball", 0], ["is", 0], ["red", 0], ["and", 0], ["car", 0]],
          ["The", 0], ["boy", 0], ["is", 0], ["and", 0], ["man", 0], ["tall", 0]]
```

Goals:

Iterate over `list_b`, pick up the specific `string` and check if it is in `list_a` and if so, increase the specific `int` by 1.
Important in that context is that I will only compare `list_a[0]` with `list_b[0]` and `list_a[1]` with `list_b[1]`.
When finished it should look like that:

```
list_a = [["the", "ball", "is", "red", "and", "the", "car", "is", "red"],
          ["the", "boy", "is", "tall", "and", "the", "man", "is", "tall"]]
list_b = [["the", 2], ["ball", 1], ["is", 2], ["red", 2], ["and", 1], ["car", 1]],
          ["the", 2], ["boy", 1], ["is", 2], ["and", 1], ["man", 1], ["tall", 2]]
```

`for loops` give me massive problems and it seems that this approach is wrong and not suitable for this task, so I am open and thankful for different solutions.

Comment: This doesnt make sense because `list_a[0]` is the entire list, `["the", "ball", "is", "red", "and", "the", "car", "is", "red"]`. Do you mean `list_a[0][0]` with `list_b[0][0]`?

Comment: For loops are the correct way to do this. Show what you did as a [mre] and we can help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: And `list_b[0][5]` is "car" but `list_a[0][5]` is `the` so how do they compare?

Comment: Since you want to iterate over both lists in parallel so that you have the `i`th elements of both at the same time, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-do-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel

Comment: It looks as if you don't need to initialize `list_b` at all. You can generate the required `list_b` starting from an empty dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` and find the index of each row in `list_b` and base row_index, Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=enumerate#collections.Counter) for `list_a` and update value in each sublist of each row in `list_b`.

```
from collections import Counter

for row, lst_b in enumerate(list_b):
    cnt_list_a = Counter(list_a[row])
    for lst in lst_b:
        lst[1] = cnt_list_a[lst[0].lower()]
    
print(list_b)
```

Output:

```
[
    [['the', 2], ['ball', 1], ['is', 2], ['red', 2], ['and', 1], ['car', 1]], 
    [['The', 2], ['boy', 1], ['is', 2], ['and', 1], ['man', 1], ['tall', 2]]
]
```